# Get first lines from string (w/o processing entire string)

Tags: ruby, string, split

I know that

```
my_str.split("\n").first
```

gives me the first line of the string.

But sadly that cuts the entire string into an array. If that string is several MB in size and I only need the first 5 lines then... There's gotta be a better alternative. I could write my own method to process the string character by character but there is probably some better method or even a build-in one for what I need?

Comment: what about the `head -n 5 <filename>` command?

Comment: I don't understand what that is. It's not a string command and there's no file involved by the way. It's just a big string in memory.

Comment: It only helps if you have a file, sorry!

Comment: Where does the string come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [`String#each_line`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-each_line):

```
my_str.each_line.take(5)
```